# How does the Axiom of Extensionality prove the uniqueness of Specified sets?

Tags: set-theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification says:

> Note that there is one axiom for every such predicate φ; thus, this is an axiom schema.
>
> To understand this axiom schema, note that the set B must be a subset of A. Thus, what the axiom schema is really saying is that, given a set A and a predicate P, we can find a subset B of A whose members are precisely the members of A that satisfy P. **By the axiom of extensionality this set is unique**

(Emphasis added)

My question is why, by the axiom of extensionality, is this set unique? The Axiom of Extensionality is about set equality; what is the relation between the Axiom of Extensionality with uniqueness of this set?

Comment: How would you prove uniqueness without proving equality? And how would you prove equality without the axiom of extensionality?

Comment: What "unique" **means** is that there are not two **non-equal** things that both have the property in question. So "unqueness" is inherently about equality.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have some predicate $\varphi$ and let $X, Y \subseteq Z$ be such that $\forall{x} (x \in X \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$ and $\forall{x} (x \in Y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$ (by specification). By a simple substitution of equivalents,

$$x \in X \leftrightarrow \varphi(x) \leftrightarrow x \in Y.$$

By extensionality, $\forall{x} (x \in X \leftrightarrow x \in Y) \rightarrow X = Y$. But $\forall{x} (x \in X \leftrightarrow x \in Y)$. So $X = Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B_1$ is a set such that every member is a member of $A$ satisfying $P$ and $B_2$ is also a set such that every member is a member of $A$ satisfying $P$. Then $x \in B_1$ iff $x \in A \land Px$ iff $x \in B_2$. So by extensionality $B_1 = B_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, extensionality asserts that if two sets contain the same elements then they are the same set. Note that the $\in$ relation is just a binary relation. You can find binary relations R and element x and y such that $(\forall c)(c R x \Leftrightarrow c R y)$, but $x \neq y$. So extensionality is necessary if your set theory is to behave as usual.

Now suppose that Z is a set and $\varphi$ is a formula in the language of set theory. Suppose A and B are two subsets of Z satisfying the axiom of specification for the formula $\varphi$. A and B consist of exactly those elements of Z that satisfies $\varphi$. In particular, A and B consist of exact the same elements. By extensionaly, it can be concluded that $A = B$.